# Asyncio not timing out

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have these two functions, based on documentation I would expect function 2 to timeout in 5s, but I don't see the timeout happening. Since the `wait_for` is creating a task and running `run_service`, shouldn't the timeout kill the task and pass control back to function 1? In the logs I see that function 1 continues to run for far longer than 5s (basically till its complete). Whats wrong here?

```
async def run(self, obs: Observable): #function 1
        await obs\
            .map(self.parse)\
            .map(self.run_service_with_timeout)\
            .run_until_complete()

async def run_service_with_timeout(self, args): #function 2
         try:
             return await asyncio.wait_for(self.run_service(args), 5)
         except asyncio.TimeoutError:
             print("Timed out")
```

Comment: But you're calling `run_service_with_timeout` once for EACH observable, and after all of those have finished, you then call `run_until_complete`, which will not have a timeout.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I am new to asyncio and this concept in general. If `run_service_with_timeout` is called by the observable and times out, what is there in `run_until_complete` to continue running? What is this running anymore? Sorry if that is a stupid question

Comment: Just remember, in a sequence of `a.b().c().d()`, `b` gets called and must finish before `c` can be called, and `c` must return before `d` can be called.